# Reading Regular Expression From Right To left is not working

Tags: php, regex

I need the string `Live-tv-channel-nbc-130pm-1000pm-s2-1.html` to be converted to `Live-tv-channel-nbc`  , That is i need to remove The part 130pm-1000pm-s2-1.html (This values are dynamic values)

I tried below code

```
$str = "Live-tv-channel-nbc-130pm-1000pm-s2-1.html";
$title = preg_replace("/-(.*?)-(.*?)-(.*?)-(\d+).html$/","",$str;
echo $title;
```

I read the stack overflow that adding $ at the end will read the str from right to left but it does not seems to work.

**Note** :Also i will be using this regex to get the values 130pm , 1000pm  ,s2 , 1 (This are dynamic values)

Answer (score 1):

You may use the following short regex to remove the last four hyphen-separated parts and the ".html" file extension:

```
/(?:-[^-]+){4}\.html$/
```

a non-capturing group (`(?:`...`)`) consisting of a hyphen (`-`) followed by one or more non-hyphens (`[^-]+`), repeated four times (`{4}`), followed by a dot character (`\.` - note that the dot is escaped!) and `html`, and finally end-of-line (`$`).

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to Regex, you can do that with a direct approach using explode and array_chunk

```
$strArray = explode("-", "Live-tv-channel-nbc-130pm-1000pm-s2-1.html");
$arrayparts   = (array_chunk($strArray, 4));
echo implode("-", $arrayparts[0]);
```